# Flutter TextField with controller resetting after TextInputType change

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using a fullscreen dialog in my app to make the user input values into text fields. Some of these values are Strings and some are ints. So I want to change the keyboard accordingly to make the unnecessary keys disappear. Here's my implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meal_tracker/model/food_model.dart';

class AddFoodDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController(),
      carbsController = TextEditingController(),
      fatController = TextEditingController(),
      proteinController = TextEditingController(),
      amountController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Food"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "SAVE",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _handleSave(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
          child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
              controller: nameController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Carbs per 100g"),
              controller: carbsController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Fat per 100g"),
              controller: fatController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Protein per 100g"),
              controller: proteinController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Amount in g"),
              controller: amountController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  void _handleSave(BuildContext context) {
    print("Dialog text: " + nameController.text);
    Navigator.of(context).pop(Food(
        name: nameController.text,
        carbsPer100g: double.parse(carbsController.text),
        fatPer100g: double.parse(fatController.text),
        proteinPer100g: double.parse(proteinController.text),
        amount: double.parse(amountController.text)));
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I input something in the "Name" TextField, which has `TextInputType.text` and then tap into another one of the TextFields, which has `TextInputType.number`, the "Name" field clears out for no apparent reason. That also happens the other way around.

Comment: You need to create a StatefulWidget and place your controllers on State.  Adding mutable fields to a StatelessWidget won't work

Comment: Do you any way of avoiding bulk of TextEditingControllers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had to put the TextEditingControllers inside a Stateful Widget, that did end up working. Thanks to Jonah Williams for the fast reply!

Comment: You guys saved my day. Thank you guys

Answer (score 7):

In your case you had to declare a StatefulWidget. A similar issue can be caused if the controllers are defined inside the build function

Answer (score 6):

TextFields value resets can happen due to 2 main reasons

- Stateless Widget
- Declaring property of TextEditingController as `final`.

If you want to handle states of any widget especially inside Dialogue (SimpleDialog) always create a separate StatefulWidget class and TextEditingController property as variable `var`.

Below is the complete example of Stateful widget which will not reset TextFields values on switching

```
class ReportDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReportDialogState createState() => new _ReportDialogState();
}

class _ReportDialogState extends State<ReportDialog> {
  var selectedConfiguration = SharedConfiguration().selectedConfiguration;
  var titleTextField = TextEditingController();
  var descriptionTextField = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final reportButton = ReusableWidgets.getButton('REPORT',
        Colors.redAccent, Colors.white, reportButtonAction, context, 46);

    return SimpleDialog(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          controller: titleTextField,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(),
            hintText: 'Title',
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
        new TextField(
          controller: descriptionTextField,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(),
            hintText: 'Add your message here...',
            helperText: 'Keep it short, this is just a demo.',
          ),
          maxLines: 6,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        reportButton
      ],
    );
  }

  void reportButtonAction() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

Hope it is useful :)